# Software for creating cable schematics

Tags: schematics, cables, software, drawing

I'm looking for free software to create drawings of communication cables eg. DE-9, RJ-45, Ribbon Cables, and Molex. I can't seem to find any software that comes with images of the connectors that can also be used to show how the cable is wired. I've done some cable drawings by hand, but I'm really looking for a way to create more professional looking drawings without spending days creating the connector drawings myself in AutoCAD. I’d like to find software like Fritzing, but with a bigger collection of parts. They have DB-25, but not DE-9. What software do people use to create drawings of a cable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think there is good software for this.  Most people use Visio or a clone.  For example, [here's](http://www.leftandwrite.com/brian/content/content.php?id=19) a library of connectors for Visio.  And you can change connector colors for different wire colors, add notes for sizes, etc.  Otherwise I think there's not much - this is one of those million-dollar ideas that I stare in the face and ignore on a daily basis.

Comment: Those are really good for A/V connectors and DE-9. I've used Visio in the past for this. I just didn't have a good set of stencils. Do you know where I could find some stencils for RJ-45 plugs and receptacles?

Comment: That took less than one second of Googling.  It's not like I'm a special internet expert - try it yourself!

Answer (score 3):

Fritzing has user submitted parts at:
http://code.google.com/p/fritzing/issues/detail?id=875

Answer (score 0):

There's not even that much available if you're willing to spend thousands.

[Here's](https://www.solidworks.com/sw/products/3d-cad/electrical-cable-harness-and-conduit-design.htm) a teaser from Solidworks.

Comment: I wonder what harness makers use

Comment: I was told what Bombardier use- IIRC something that works with CATIA. So far, AFAIK, they have not had any problems like Airbus A380 had with the cables being too short to plug together. LOL.  The job shops probably have to work with whatever their customers throw at them- hand drawn, Visio, Autocad, Solidworks, CATIA, Pro-E etc.

Comment: I'd certainly want to see a library of all the common connectors included for the problem domain- Military circular connectors, Delphi connectors, Molex, JST etc.